Compile time type conversion problem with Arduino esp32 preferences.h
I'm trying to read an SSID using preferences.h but getting a compile time error which doesn't seem to make sense to me.
According to the Arduino docs, preferences.getString() can return either a char* or a String but I'm getting a type conversion error.
error: cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' in assignment
  533 |   ssid = netPrefs.getString("ssid","");
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                            |
      |                            String

exit status 1

Compilation error: cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' in assignment

netPrefs and ssid is declared in the global scope (i.e. before setup()) as follows:
const char* ssid = "myssid";
Preferences netPrefs;

and in setup() I create the preferences store as follows:
netPrefs.begin("network-info", false);

The line causing the problem is simply:
void readPrefs() {
  ssid = netPrefs.getString("ssid","");
}

which is being called from setup().
I guess I must be missing something.

Can you add a link to the docs? The ones I'm looking at say getString returns a size_t or String. You are calling the overload that returns a String getString(const char* key, String defaultValue = String()); Since const char* ssid = "myssid";, you are trying to assign 'String' to 'const char*'.

You might be able to do ssid = netPrefs.getString("ssid").c_str();, but I'd be careful of that going out of scope. Probably the best option is to change to String ssid("myssid");

@001 Doh! Don;t ask me how.. I was reading the docs as getString returning char* and/or String.. but you are absolutely right they say size_t and/or String. I have no idea why I was misreading it like that - and I have been for two day now!

I was concerned about just switching ssid (and password) to Strings as I was not sure if I'd find compatability issues with the wifi.h library if I did that, however having tried the change it looks like it's still compiling OK. I'll continue with that change and see if I get tripped up anywhere else as that is certainly an easy fix for the preferences parts.

The Preferences::getString() has two overloaded methods according to documentation.
size_t getString(const char* key, char* value, size_t len);

and
String getString(const char* key, String defaultValue = String());

If you are using a char array for ssid, then the first method is designed for the purpose.
char my_ssid[33]{'\0'};  // max SSID is 32-char per WiFi spec
if (netPrefs.getString("ssid", my_ssid, sizeof(my_ssid)) {
  // my_ssid contains the ssid copied from Preferences
}
else {
  // error in getting the SSID from Preferences
}

If you prefer to get the SSID in Arduino String object, then use the second overload method.
String my_ssid = netPrefs.getString("ssid");

if (my_ssid) != "") {
  // my_ssid contains the valid ssid
}
else {
  // my_ssid is invalid as it returns "" String
}



netPrefs.getString() returns a temporary object of type String. You're trying to assign that to a C string i.e. a pointer char. No type conversion exists to make this possible.
You may be tempted to call ssid = netPrefs.getString("ssid").c_str(); but this creates a memory allocation bug. Since the object returned by getString() is temporary, you will receive a pointer to a temporarily allocated memory buffer. This buffer is released immediately after the line is finished executing and ssid now points to a random unused address in heap which probably gets overwritten later on.
If you really want to store ssid as a C string, then you have to allocate memory to store the value, then manually copy value from netPrefs.getString("ssid").c_str() to it. E.g.:
char ssid[128];
strncpy(ssid, sizeof(ssid), netPrefs.getString("ssid").c_str());

A much easier solution is to create ssid of type String which automatically manages its memory and copies the new value on assignment. If you need a C string from it down the road, just call c_str().
String ssid;
ssid = netPrefs.getString("ssid");
...
some_c_api_call(ssid.c_str());


The char* use was simply because that seems to be recommended in all of the examples I have seen for using wifi.h. tbh I have always tried to avoid manual memory allocation as I am in no way near a good enough coder to not make a complete mess of that! (I know I should learn, but it just seems like a route full of pitfalls). I was also concerned that simply switching the WiFi params (that I want to store) over to Strings might raise compatability issues with wifi.h functions, but it seems OK so far.

Well, I've found the 'strangeness' that I feared when switching the char*s to Strings. Storing a WiFi password as a String seems to corrupt it - or at least it looks corrupted when outputting the string to a webpage (this is without retrieving from preferences, just the raw variable output to a web client!). Storing that as char* works perfectly. More investigation needed, but it looks like there may be a problem using String for the WiFi password.

Actually, thinking about it, I guess it's not corruption but de-allocated memory I am seeing. Random characters that change with every reload of the webpage that displays the value... the SSID is fine, but the password is not - I guess that's just luck. So I need to figure out the 'proper' way using char*...
